# cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [7]' to 'LPSTR' | C++

Tags: c++

i am trying to use a fuction that extract file from my project (ressources) but i get errors while i build it.

here is the fuction to extract :

```
void extract(WORD wResId, LPSTR lpszOutputPath)
{ //example: Extract(IDB_BITMAP1, "Redrose.bmp");
HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(wResId), _TEXT("BINARY"));
HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc);
LPVOID lpLock = LockResource(hLoaded);
DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpszOutputPath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, NULL);
DWORD dwByteWritten;
WriteFile(hFile, lpLock, dwSize, &dwByteWritten, NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);
FreeResource(hLoaded);}
```

And this is where the error appear :

```
extract(1005, "checker.bat");
```

error :

> cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [7]' to 'LPSTR'

My project is x64 Release and my project is set to multi-Bytes.
Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Make your code `const`-correct: change `void extract(WORD wResId, LPSTR lpszOutputPath)` to `void extract(WORD wResId, LPCSTR lpszOutputPath)`.

Comment: It says `const char[12]` in the screenshot (as would be expected)

Comment: The string type needs to match the first parameter of `CreateFile` too. (which is `LPCTSTR`). One solution would be to call `CreateFileA` rather than `CreateFile`, or otherwise `extract` could take `LPCTSTR` depending on how you obtain data for it.

Comment: Paul you are the man !

Comment: fast and right answer :) fixed, thanks to everyone that answered fast !